# St. John Henry Newman on Conscience and the Pope

Tags: catholicism, papacy, anglicanism, pope-francis, conscience

Here ([*On Conscience and the Pope*](https://www.newmanreader.org/works/anglicans/volume2/gladstone/section5.html)) is found an essay written by St. John Henry Newman. It begins as follows:

> IT seems, then, that there are extreme cases in which Conscience may come into collision with the word of a Pope, and is to be followed in spite of that word.

I found this essay published in 1875 by The Catholic Publication Society here: [*A Letter Addressed to the Duke of Norfolk on Occasion of Mr. Gladstone's Recent Expostulation:
Certain Difficulties Felt by Anglicans in Catholic Teaching*](https://ia904704.us.archive.org/10/items/a678635200newmuoft/a678635200newmuoft.pdf). The link contains an expanded title.

However, this book has neither Approbation or Imprimatur by competant ecclesiastical authority.

QUESTION: Does anyone know of a publication which contains the above essay; and which comes with a valid Imprimatur? Preferably, the book will be accessible online. If not, that's O.K. too.

Answer (score 2):

Are you questioning the orthodoxy of it?

For a critical assessment, cf.

- ch. 9 on papal infallibility, which discusses the famed *Letter to the Duke of Norfolk*,
- ch. 15, which discusses conscience,

of Rev. Paul M. Kimball, [*Cardinal Newman: Trojan Horse in the Church*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=9175).

Comment: +1 Thank you for your answer. I expect to look into it further. I apologize for the delay in my response. but my SE accounts were hacked in early February and it was a long process in getting my identity and points restored to all my SE accounts.